# TestMethodWithoutAssertionOrExpectedException

Tags: jqassistant

I have the following Rule:

```
[[junit4:C_TestMethodWithoutAssertion]]
.All Unit Tests must either use a expected Exception or call an Assert Method.
[source,cypher,role=constraint,requiresConcepts="junit4:TestClass,junit4:AssertMethod,junit4:TestMethod",severity=blocker]
----
MATCH
  (testType:Type)-[:DECLARES]->(testMethod:Test:Method)
  -[:ANNOTATED_BY]-(annotation:Annotation)-[:OF_TYPE]->(atype:Type)
WHERE
atype.fqn="org.junit.Test"
AND NOT testMethod.abstract
AND NOT (annotation)-[:HAS]->(:Value{name:"expected"})
AND NOT (testMethod)-[:INVOKES*..3]->(:Method:Assert)
RETURN
  testType AS DeclaringType,
  testMethod AS Method
----
```

if I use it in the neo4j browser, the rule works perfectly.
But if I use it for a Report in an adoc file, I get a lot of "FalsePositives".
Has anyone an Idea.

LG Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last query does not return results because the abstract part filters too much. Here's a fixed and slightly restructured version:

`MATCH
  (testType:Type)-[:DECLARES]->(testMethod:Test:Method)
  -[:ANNOTATED_BY]-(annotation:Annotation)-[:OF_TYPE]->(atype:Type)
WHERE
  atype.fqn="org.junit.Test"
  AND NOT (has(testMethod.abstract) AND testMethod.abstract)
  AND NOT (
    (annotation)-[:HAS]->(:Value{name:"expected"})
    OR (testMethod)-[:INVOKES*..3]->(:Method:Assert)
)
RETURN
  testType AS DeclaringType,
  testMethod AS Method`

Comment: Note that the "expected" value of the annotation could be refactored to another concept creating a relation between the test method and the expected exception type.

Comment: I modified it to AND NOT (has(testMethod.abstract) AND testMethod.abstract), and now it works. Thanx

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok now I bracket "()" the NOT statements, and so it works:

```
[[junit4:C_TestMethodWithoutAssertion]]
.All Unit Tests must either use a expected Exception or call an Assert Method.
[source,cypher,role=constraint,requiresConcepts="junit4:TestClass,junit4:AssertMethod,junit4:TestMethod",severity=blocker]
----
MATCH
  (testType:Type)-[:DECLARES]->(testMethod:Test:Method)
  -[:ANNOTATED_BY]-(annotation:Annotation)-[:OF_TYPE]->(atype:Type)
WHERE
atype.fqn="org.junit.Test"
AND NOT (testMethod.abstract)
AND NOT ((annotation)-[:HAS]->(:Value{name:"expected"}))
AND NOT ((testMethod)-[:INVOKES*..3]->(:Method:Assert))
RETURN
  testType AS DeclaringType,
  testMethod AS Method
----
```